# VS2019 does not expand macros for library directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

For some reason VS stopped expanding library path macros for a particular project, which prevents it from building. This is what I see for this project:

[image]

For another project in the same solution everything works just fine:

[image]

Note that putting $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64) in the project specific paths expands the macro properly, it only fails for inherited values.

How can this happen?